# Flutter pass data from DropdownButton to api

Tags: flutter, dart

I just wanted to map to api and make the following DropdownButton in flutter that posts data to API when an item is selected

```
DropdownButton(
                value: 'Item 1',
                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items: [
                  'Item 1',
                  'Item 2',
                  'Item 3',
                  'Item 4',
                  'Item 5',
                ].map((String items) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: items,
                    child: Text(items),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: print),
```

how can I map to api endpoint and post the selected item to api?

Answer (score 0):

As a post request with an integer instead of string:

```
Future<void> onChangedCallback(int? item) async {
   if(item != null){
     currentValue = item;
     final url = "your_url_here";
     final body = {
          "key_you_want_to_map": item
        };  
     final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: body);
     print(response.body);
   }
}

...

var currentValue = 1;

DropdownButton(
                value: currentValue,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items: <int>[
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                ].map((int i) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: i,
                    child: Text('Item $i'),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: onChangedCallback,
                ), // Equivalent of onChanged: (v) async => onChangedCallback(v),
```

Comment: But I'm having the error (The argument type 'Future<void> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'.) on onChanged: onChangedCallback,

Comment: It's a type safe error, you can use `onChangedCallback(String? item)` and apply a null check on the item, I updated the response

Comment: Okay thanks. and how can I change the post item name to a number.....like if the user selects 'item 1' it post 1, it post 2 if 'item 2 ' is selected etc

Comment: You should change the entire widget, instead of passing a String to it you should pass an integer, I'll update the answer

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I'm checking it out. Can we chat up for further help, please?

Comment: Yes, feel free to add me in Discord: Hyla#0556

Comment: okay. I've added you there